# Measuring area using correct CRS and units in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, area, units

I have uploaded a shapefile and I am simply trying to calculate some simple areas of provinces (and I know their areas from Wikipedia). My map is from Zimbabwe, and I have saved the project, reprojected all layers, and saved everything as WGS 84 / UTM Zone 36S. The units are all in metres.

When I use $AREA function in field calculator, the areas come around very very small. I expect areas in order the thousands of square kilometers, but I get numbers like 3m2.

Why are my results so far out?

Edit: I've added images of the property settings

[image: Project properties]

[image: Layer properties]

Comment: Because your calculations are done using a geographic CRS instead of a projected one. Make sure the layer is actually saved using the correct UTM zone.

Comment: Sorry, but I thought saving everything as WGS 84/UTM Zone 36S would be a projected CRS. Is this not a UTM CRS?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your screenshots it seems you did not reproject layer but defined (wrong) layer CRS.
To reproject layer if actually needed, you need to export layer it and on export define desired CRS.

Check 'General Project Settings' what units are set for area measurments:

[image]

And Settings menu, Options:

[image]

Comment: I can't see the map tools option in QGIS (I'm using QGIS 3.6 - do I need an additional plugin?) but everything under general says meters, rather than degrees, and the area is measured in square metres. What could be going wrong?

Comment: @MichaelHammond it can be found under Settings > Options

Comment: Thanks. Still, everything seems to be in metres, in a UTM projection, etc. I can't see why I'm getting funny units

Comment: Try ctrl+shift+J what values you get. Where did you get shapefile. Is it possible its not in actual scale? Try loading OpenStreetMap to make sure. You can use Open Layers plugin for that..

Comment: When I do that ctrl + shift + J, I get m2, but everything is very small (the country is only 3m across!). I got the shapefiles from a project colleague. When I originally had the files, they opened with OSM fine as a background. However, I then reprojected from a WGS 84 to this CRS that should be a UTM CRS. I think that's where the problem may be

Comment: I may have solved the problem, but I'm not sure I understand why. If I keep things in WGS 84, and calculate everything in metres. It seems to the UTM thing that messes it up. I'm not sure I understand why however. Perhaps I shouldn't have reprojected to UTM

Comment: Maybe you didnt actualy reproject but just defined layer projection? If you changeed CRS under layer properties you only defined (wrong) projection of layer data not reproject. You should leave data as is and reproject only by changing project CRS if needed. Or Export layer and on export change to desired projection.

Comment: Thanks, I used the Reproject Layer tool - still exporting it might be easier. It is doing broadly what I want it to do now, that that's good. Thanks for your help